# How to expand answer form

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a very nice layout of a list of comments with response example.

```css
/**
 * Oscuro: #283035
 * Azul: #03658c
 * Detalle: #c7cacb
 * Fondo: #dee1e3
 ----------------------------------*/
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 a {
  color: #03658c;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif, Verdana;
 background: #dee1e3;
}

/** ====================
 * Lista de Comentarios
 =======================*/
.comments-container {
 margin: 60px auto 15px;
 width: 768px;
}

.comments-container h1 {
 font-size: 36px;
 color: #283035;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.comments-container h1 a {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.comments-list {
 margin-top: 30px;
 position: relative;
}

/**
 * Lineas / Detalles
 -----------------------*/
.comments-list:before {
 content: '';
 width: 2px;
 height: 100%;
 background: #c7cacb;
 position: absolute;
 left: 32px;
 top: 0;
}

.comments-list:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background: #c7cacb;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 27px;
 width: 7px;
 height: 7px;
 border: 3px solid #dee1e3;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.reply-list:before, .reply-list:after {display: none;}
.reply-list li:before {
 content: '';
 width: 60px;
 height: 2px;
 background: #c7cacb;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25px;
 left: -55px;
}


.comments-list li {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}

.comments-list li:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
}

.reply-list {
 padding-left: 88px;
 clear: both;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
/**
 * Avatar
 ---------------------------*/
.comments-list .comment-avatar {
 width: 65px;
 height: 65px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 99;
 float: left;
 border: 3px solid #FFF;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 overflow: hidden;
}

.comments-list .comment-avatar img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.reply-list .comment-avatar {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}

.comment-main-level:after {
 content: '';
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 display: block;
 clear: both;
}
/**
 * Caja del Comentario
 ---------------------------*/
.comments-list .comment-box {
 width: 680px;
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

.comments-list .comment-box:before, .comments-list .comment-box:after {
 content: '';
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 border-width: 10px 12px 10px 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: transparent #FCFCFC;
 top: 8px;
 left: -11px;
}

.comments-list .comment-box:before {
 border-width: 11px 13px 11px 0;
 border-color: transparent rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 left: -12px;
}

.reply-list .comment-box {
 width: 610px;
}
.comment-box .comment-head {
 background: #FCFCFC;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.comment-box .comment-head i {
 float: right;
 margin-left: 14px;
 position: relative;
 top: 2px;
 color: #A6A6A6;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: color 0.3s ease;
 transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.comment-box .comment-head i:hover {
 color: #03658c;
}

.comment-box .comment-name {
 color: #283035;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 700;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.comment-box .comment-name a {
 color: #283035;
}

.comment-box .comment-head span {
 float: left;
 color: #999;
 font-size: 13px;
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
}

.comment-box .comment-content {
 background: #FFF;
 padding: 12px;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #595959;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
 border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.comment-box .comment-name.by-author, .comment-box .comment-name.by-author a {color: #03658c;}
.comment-box .comment-name.by-author:after {
 content: 'autor';
 background: #03658c;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding: 3px 5px;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-left: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

/** =====================
 * Responsive
 ========================*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
 .comments-container {
  width: 480px;
 }

 .comments-list .comment-box {
  width: 390px;
 }

 .reply-list .comment-box {
  width: 320px;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/font-awesome/4.0.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="comments-container">
  <h1>Comments</h1>

  <ul id="comments-list" class="comments-list">
   <li>
    <div class="comment-main-level">
     <!-- Avatar -->
     <div class="comment-avatar"><img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_1_zps8e1c80cd.jpg" alt=""></div>
     <!-- Contenedor del Comentario -->
     <div class="comment-box">
      <div class="comment-head">
       <h6 class="comment-name by-author"><a href="http://creaticode.com/blog">Agustin Ortiz</a></h6>
       <span>20 minutes ago</span>
       <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
       <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-content">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Respuestas de los comentarios -->
    <ul class="comments-list reply-list">
     <li>
      <!-- Avatar -->
      <div class="comment-avatar"><img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_2_zps7de12f8b.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <!-- Contenedor del Comentario -->
      <div class="comment-box">
       <div class="comment-head">
        <h6 class="comment-name"><a href="http://creaticode.com/blog">Lorena Rojero</a></h6>
        <span>10 minutes ago</span>
        <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
       </div>
       <div class="comment-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>

     <li>
      <!-- Avatar -->
      <div class="comment-avatar"><img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_1_zps8e1c80cd.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <!-- Contenedor del Comentario -->
      <div class="comment-box">
       <div class="comment-head">
        <h6 class="comment-name by-author"><a href="http://creaticode.com/blog">Agustin Ortiz</a></h6>
        <span>10 minutes ago</span>
        <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
       </div>
       <div class="comment-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>

   <li>
    <div class="comment-main-level">
     <!-- Avatar -->
     <div class="comment-avatar"><img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_2_zps7de12f8b.jpg" alt=""></div>
     <!-- Contenedor del Comentario -->
     <div class="comment-box">
      <div class="comment-head">
       <h6 class="comment-name"><a href="http://creaticode.com/blog">Lorena Rojero</a></h6>
       <span>10 minutes ago</span>
       <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
       <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-content">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

I need a little functionality that is to show a box design to write the response comment

I've looked for some [examples (by jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/fL1ywcr7/3/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csg2h6Lb/), but the problem goes beyond just showing a response field, you should also get the id of the post by clicking on the answer icon

To then be able to comment and send the comment through ajax

My idea:

[image]

Comment: There is not `js` in your code, have you tried anything for the reply, expand?

Comment: This [snippet](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/PjPa) may be worth looking at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like so:

1. Add `data-comment_id` attribute to each `LI` in the `UL#comments-list`, so that we know which comment is being replied to. I also added `comment` to the `class` attribute:

   ```
   <li class="comment" data-comment_id="1">
   ```
2. Add the "Reply" button/link after `div.comment-content` inside the above `LI`:

   ```
   <button type="button" class="comment-reply-link">Reply</button>
   ```
3. Use a single comment reply form and place it after the comments container (i.e. `div.comments-container`):

   ```html
   <div id="comment-reply">
     <h3>Leave a Reply</h3>
     <form method="post" action="">
       <input type="hidden" class="post-id" value="123">
       <div class="form-field">
         <input class="comment-name" placeholder="Name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-field">
         <textarea class="comment-content" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
       </div>
       <button type="button" class="submit">Post Comment</button>
       <button type="button" class="cancel">Cancel Reply</button>
     </form>
   </div>
   ```

   And if you see the markup above, I put the post ID in a hidden `input` with `class` `post-id`.

Now for the JavaScript parts..

1. Move the comment reply form (to the appropriate comment wrapper):

   ```
   $(document).on('click', '.comment-reply-link', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     // Show the previously clicked button.
     $('#comment-reply').closest('.comment')
       .find('.comment-reply-link').show();

     // Hide the button.
     $(this).hide();

     // Move the comment reply form wrapper.
     $('#comment-reply').insertAfter(this)
       .find('.comment-name').focus()                // focus on the Name field
       .end().find('.cancel').removeClass('hidden'); // show the cancel button
   });
   ```
2. Cancel comment reply:

   ```
   $('#comment-reply').on('click', '.cancel', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     this.blur();

     // Show the previously clicked button.
     $(this).closest('.comment')
       .find('.comment-reply-link').show();

     // Place the comment reply form back to its initial position.
     $('#comment-reply')
       .find('.cancel').addClass('hidden')        // show the cancel button
       .end().insertAfter('.comments-container'); // and then move the form
   });
   ```
3. And when the "Post Comment" button is clicked:

   ```
   $('#comment-reply').on('click', '.submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     const $comment = $(this).closest('.comment');

     // Get the post and comment IDs.
     const comment_id = $comment.data('comment_id');
     const post_id = $('#comment-reply').find('.post-id').val();
     console.log(post_id, comment_id);

     // Here you can make your AJAX call...
   });
   ```

### Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sdpk9htv/).

But... it's up to you to further improve the styling (i.e. CSS code).

Comment: Hi friend :) The cancel reply options did not work for me, so I added the jquery code to the whole this `$(function() { ...all code });` now if they work, but it shows the form to answer the comment without having made any option for it to be displayed https://jsfiddle.net/mhostingfree/mj3b5xz0/2/.

Comment: Hi Lou. Sorry, can you re-explain the issue? Did you mean that you want the comment reply form to be initially hidden? If so, using CSS (`display: none`) would do it. Btw, yes, sorry about that - in your project, the whole code should be in `jQuery(function($){ // here })`

Comment: So, all is good, no? However, one thing you should know, is that when the "cancel" link is clicked, the comment reply form doesn't go back into where it was initially; but it can be changed of course. Let me know if you'd like me to change that (behavior).

Comment: If you add it please, yes friend.

Comment: Friend I found a tutorial of a complete comment system, but you have the same problem with this question. You think you have time and that you can add the same to show, cancel and hide answer form to [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/mhostingfree/dhj2kwco/2/) please, I beg you to help me, and the demonstration of how are the comments [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mhostingfree/azsubow3/1/)

Comment: Lou, sorry but that seems quite a different thing to the one in the question despite they have similarities. Nonetheless, where did you find the tutorial? What its URL? Have you already implemented it on *your site*? If so, what's the URL if it can be shared?

Comment: Hello friend, I have not yet implemented it on my website I'm doing tests on localhost, this is the [tutorial](https://www.baulphp.com/sistema-de-comentarios-php-me-gusta-y-no-me-gusta/amp/) is in Spanish, I use that language a bit.

Comment: Here the tutorial translated into [English](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&nv=1&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=es&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://www.baulphp.com/sistema-de-comentarios-php-me-gusta-y-no-me-gusta/amp/&xid=17259,15700022,15700186,15700190,15700253,15700256,15700259&usg=ALkJrhis78aGFu_NrJJDpbFqFSA94FEdKQ) using the Google translator.

Comment: I updated the answer, just in case you'd like to see the new demo. And for the extra thing, please follow the steps [here](https://gist.github.com/5ally/79d61f08c99552ae4856fe91113ec953).